# Override spring data save method

Tags: spring, save, spring-data, entity

I have created a **BaseRepository** which extends `CrudRepository` and is tagged with `@NoRepositoryBean`. All my other repositories extend **BaseRepository**.

How can I override the `save` method in my **BaseRepository** to have custom error messages? For example I need to catch all `DataIntegrityViolationException` to show some proper message on front-end side. Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

For example, if you create Spring Endpoints (`@Endpoint`) then you can create a class which implements `org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointInterceptor` where you can monitor all the traffic. Is there a similar class where I can monitor all the data related traffic?

Comment: Why would you need to override the `save` method for that? You can do that in your service or simply use an aspect to do that for you.

Comment: And it is actually impossible to do that by overwriting the save methodo when using JPA, because save might never get called and the exceptions get thrown when the transaction commits (flushing the EM)

Comment: If I would override it in my service, then I would have to create a service for every repository I have. Maybe I don't have to override the save method but some other class where all the repository related traffic goes through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in my comment overriding 'save' won't achieve your goal. JPA might throw exceptions all over your code. This is one of the problems of JPA.

I guess you could overwrite some central method of Spring to achieve your goal but that really isn't how Spring works.

In stead you basically register your exception handling so, it gets invoked by Spring as desired.

There is [an article about this by Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring), which looks promising and is valued high by Google.

Comment: Thank you very much, this part: "New Solution 3 – The New @ControllerAdvice (Spring 3.2 And Above)" solved my problem.